# HTML source validation errors

Tags: html

How would I fix this code for it to be validated in html 5 correctly? When I test my page in Chrome, it shows the page correctly, but I am validating with errors...

```html
<div class="form">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="flexBox">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Your name">
      <input type="email" name="" id="text" placeholder="Your email">
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Your subject">
    <textarea "name" id="" cols="30" rows="8" placeholder="Your message"> 
    </textarea>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
   </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: What errors? (Other than non-unique `id` attributes....

Comment: The errors tell you exactly what is wrong. `<textarea "name"` - remove `"name"`. Remove empty id attributes. Remove empty name attributes.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your HTML code.

---

Firstly, you need to remove the `name` string on the `<textarea>` element.

I think you wanted to *set* the `name` attribute to something. In that case, you can use the code below.

```html
<textarea name="name"></textarea>
```

---

Secondly, you have to remove all of the empty `name` and `id` attributes. So, all of these:

```html
<input name="" id="" />
```

Can simply be removed.

```html
<input />
```

---

So, in summary, you need to:

1. Change the `"name"` text on the `<textarea>` element to be an attribute (and have a value).
2. Remove all empty `name` and `id` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

All the issues that have been pointed out are right. I strongly recommend you to use a *linter* within your IDE

Or check out sites like [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options) where you can paste/upload/urled your code and it will analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my corrected code which validates perfectly. Just in case someone runs into a similar issue in the future. Thanks everyone.

```
<div class="form">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="flexBox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Your email">
    </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your subject">
        <textarea cols="30" rows="8" placeholder="Your message"> 
</textarea>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```